# Use methods of one file in another file

Tags: c#, oop, namespaces

I am a beginner in C#. I have written some functions in File1.xaml.cs

I have another tester file Test.xaml.cs in which I need to test the functions I wrote in File1.xaml.cs.

How can I do that ? Both the files are under the same namespace.

Comment: Class names, method name, parameters? A bit of code would help

Comment: Show your work first.. What have you tried so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Did you add both files to the project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an instance of the second class. than you can call methods of it. Or you make the methods in the second class public.

```
public class Class1
{
   public void Function()
   { ... }
}

public class Class2
{
   public void AnotherFunction()
   {
      Class1 class1 = new Class1();
      class1.Function();
   }
}
```

Ok. Let's say that you have 2 projects in your solution "Project1" and "Project2". In Project1 you have a Class called Project1Class which contains a method "Foo" you want to use in Project2. First you have to add a Referenze to Project1 in Project2 (Right-Click References->Add Reference -> Solution->Project1). In Project2 you have a class Project2Class which contains a method "AccessProject1Class". The code of this class looks like:

```
using Project1;

namespace Project2
{
    public class Project2Class
    {
        public void AccessProject1Class()
        {
            Project1Class project1Class = new Project1Class();
            project1Class.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if Class1 lies in File1.xaml.cs and Class2 is in Test.xaml.cs, then don't I need to add something like import File1.xaml.cs in the headers of Tets.xaml.cs ?

Comment: No, because both classes are in the same namespace. If Class1 is in Project1 and Class2 is in Project2, than you have to reference Project2 in Project1

Comment: What if the namespaces of both the projects are different? How can I use the functions in File1.xaml.cs in Test.xaml.cs ?

Comment: Take a look at my updated post

Answer (score 0):

A class in File.xaml.cs should have an internal or public access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the functions you want to use as public or public shared hope this helps